# .Net 6+ Mage Manifest Signing (Click Once Deploy) Path LowerCase Couldnt Found Problem VS2022

Tags: .net, deployment, manifest, clickonce, mage

Hello software developers, helpers, leaders,

I have a project and I'm trying to deploy it with click once.
I encountered an error due to not being able to find the path while creating the manifest file.

I tried Cake.Mage, I tried the Publish section in VS2022.

I get the following error. Why does it return lower case when searching for Path? When translating, why is the capital letter "I" translated into the lowercase "ı" in Turkish?

I tried changing windows language, Vs2022 and project settings to different languages.

But I couldn't get past the problem. My test is below. I am waiting for your help.

Non Capital I Letter Sample With Publish:
[image: NonCapitalILetterSample]

With Capital I Letter Sample With Publish:
[image: WithCapitalILetterSample]

Cake.Mage Stack Trace:

```
- Stack trace:
            location: System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
            location: System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            location: System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            location: System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            location: System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            location: System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- Stack trade end before special condition ---
            location: System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            location: System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            location: System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - DOM problem. Result: 
            -HRESULT:   0x80070c81
             Start line:    0
             Endline:   0
             Main Computer File:    
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack Trace:
            location: System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)
            location: System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest..ctor(FileStream fileStream)
            konum: System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        - HRESULT exception: 0x80070C81
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack Trace:
            location: System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.CreateCMSFromXml(Byte[] buffer, UInt32 bufferSize, IManifestParseErrorCallback Callback, Guid& riid)
            location: System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)
```

Thanks for your answers.